# Как преобразовать QImage в Mat?

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv

необходимо преобразовать QImage в Mat. пытаюсь сделать это с помощью функции:

```
def QImageToCvMat(incomingImage):

    incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGBA8888)

    width = incomingImage.width()
    height = incomingImage.height()

    ptr = incomingImage.bits()
    ptr.setsize(height * width * 4)
    arr = np.frombuffer(ptr, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
    return arr
```

я передаю в `QImageToCvMat` переменную `tmp` типа `QImage` и надеюсь получить переменную `conv` типа `Mat`.

```
tmp = pic_left.pixmap().toImage()
conv = QImageToCvMat(tmp)
```

вот так я обозначил `pic_left = QGraphicsPixmapItem()` затем считал этот объект

```
pic_left.setPixmap(QPixmap(filename))
ui.srcGraphicsView.scene().addItem(pic_left)
```

`filename` - это переменная пути к файлу `filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]`

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Какая то ошибка?

Comment: Я пытаюсь открыть conv с помощью imshow. В принципе, пустое окно появляется, но потом все вылетает. Есть предложение, что что-то не так с функцией конвертации